# Highlight or match three columns cells data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any away to highlight three rows in the three columns if their data matched like below example or if there is any function it would help too, as below, I want that there should be something to highlight the number 1 and number 4 data as their data match with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Name` is in A1 try selecting A:C and a CF formula rule of:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1
```

with Fill of choice.

Answer (score 0):

## SUMPRODUCT Version

For the data range `A2:C5` use Conditional Formatting and:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$A2)*($B$2:$B$5=$B2)*($C$2:$C$5=$C2))>1
```